What are those injection tubes on characters backs named?
These tubes are commonly seen on a character that is possibly being experimented on. I’ve been trying to find the actual name of these injection tubes or trying to find if there is a specific name but I just can’t seem to find anything helpful. The only character that I can name from the top of my head with these injection tubes is Warwick from League of Legends. I’m creating a character with these injection tubes and the implants that go along with them that run down her spine. I think it is clear that my character would have holes in her back considering space of where the injection tubes should go. I hope my explanation is helpful since I’ve really been wondering on how I should design my character with these tubes and implants.

they look a lot like phlebotomy or blood collection tubes. But other characters have gas masks. I myself used the term "injector" when writing my fanfic. Like car engine injector... There's also injector pen or jet injector (medicine).

Would Bane from Batman, with his Venom injectors, be another example of what you're looking for?

https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/File:Warwick_Update_model_02.jpg

I don't know if the Borg Qeen from Star Trek counts since the "conduits" do not serve the same purpose as for Warwick, but you can find some vocabulary here.

This is Spinal Tap :)

IRL, that's an injection port although they tend to not be quite so exaggerated.

I used a port in my chest with a tube to my heart.  I would wear a portable pump connected to the port for a couple of days every two weeks for six months to pump chemotherapy through my body.  I joked that I was a part time cyborg.    Anyway, such a port could be used to pump something in or to pump something out of the body, like pumping out blood, removing something and adding something, and pumping it back in.

you are doing very well so far ... I’m not really sure how to reply to comments ... just update the question with any requested info
